# How does sshd know to invoke shell?

Tags: ssh, bash

When I type `ssh remote-host command`, `sshd` will run `bash -c command` for me.

How  does `sshd` know to invoke `bash` with `-c` option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh dammit, this is hardcoded in OpenSSH's source code.

From session.c of OpenSSH 5.9p1 source code:

```
/*
 * Execute the command using the user's shell.  This uses the -c
 * option to execute the command.
 */
argv[0] = (char *) shell0;
argv[1] = "-c";
argv[2] = (char *) command;
argv[3] = NULL;
execve(shell, argv, env);
perror(shell);
exit(1);
```

So I guess this is a POSIX standard huh?

Comment: Seems to be yes: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html